# Apple ID says it doesn't recognize your finger in the morning

Tags: iphone, apple-id

Sometimes I would wake up and try to unlock my phone and be told that it doesn't recognize my fingerprint and that I HAVE to put my passcode to enable touch id but I thought that only happened when you put your finger on the home button too much and you don't have that finger registered or something. For me as soon as I wake up it says it doesn't recognize me like I already tried it before when I know I didn't and nobody else did either. Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](https://www.imore.com/touch-id) on Touch ID. It says:

> If your passcode hasn't been used to unlock in six days, and Touch ID
>   hasn't been used to unlock in six hours, you'll need to enter your
>   passcode or password to re-enable it.

So you should expect to re-enter your password around once a week. It's a good idea, because otherwise you might not use your password for months and forget it.